# Where does Visual Studio continually build to?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-extensions

From my understanding visual studio is constantly building in order to provide things like definition look-up and intellisense, but where is this information stored?

Is it all stored within working memory, or is it stored to disc somewhere?

Is there a way to access these "partly built" collections and read from them?

I'm particularly interested in Visual Studio's capabilities with the C# language.

Is this kind of information related to the .pdb file type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C# and VB, it's stored into memory only. C++ stores some stuff in an on-disk database.

> Is there a way to access these "partly built" collections and read from them?

The only public API that exists today is the [CodeModel API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codemodel%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which lets you wak through declaration information. Depending upon your scenario it may or may not be sufficient. If it's not...sorry you're out of luck (or at least until the Roslyn project ships.)